# Create Slideshow with Fade Transition and Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, navigation, slideshow

I am trying to create a slideshow like the one on this site: 
http://www.marthastewart.com/

However, I would like to use JavaScript and CSS instead of Flash. I would be super grateful for any suggestions on how to do this. I am currently using the InnerFade plugin, which works great for the slideshow part, but I can't figure out how to integrate the navigation; I'm not even sure where to start! :) I'm open to starting over from scratch and not using InnerFade.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

For something simple you could use Jquery Cycle http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle

It's easy to integrate and supports navigation: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the Thickbox type galleries have slideshow and navigation support built in. For a pretty comprehensive (read: overwhelming) selection, check out this link;

http://planetozh.com/projects/lightbox-clones/

jQuery cycle is prob all you'll need though...

Answer (score 1):

i use this one quite often - [link](http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html)

and here are some links to other examples

[link1](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/)

[link2](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/18/30-best-solutions-for-image-galleries-slideshows-lightboxes/)

[link3](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/57-free-image-gallery-slideshow-and-lightbox-solutions/)

[link4](http://www.noupe.com/jquery/35-useful-jquery-plugins-for-slideshows-graphs-and-text-effects.html)